# Thread-Safe Query Expressions F#

Tags: multithreading, f#, parallel.foreach, type-providers, fsharp.data.sqlclient

I have a set of functions which using FSharp.Data.TypeProviders makes several calls to the database via sql to retrieve data.

The code looks like the following:

```
let query_one (firstName:string) (lastName:string) =
     query { for a in db.Names do
             where (a.firstname = FirstName && a.secondname = LastName)
             select a } |> Seq.last


let query_two (jobTitle:string)  =
     query { for a in db.Jobs do
             where (a.jobId = jobTitle)
             select a } |> Seq.last

let detailsList = new List<('a*'b)>()

let queries = 
   workerDetails 
   |> Array.Parallel.map (fun (firstn, lastn, jobt) -> 
       let j1 = query_one firstn lastn
       let j2 = query_two jobt
       detailsList.add (j1,j2) )
```

When I run this I get the following:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred
>   in FSharp.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: An item with the same key has already been
>   added.

To be more exact:

> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been
>   added.    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.EvaluateQuotation(FSharpExpr
>   e)    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.EvalNonNestedInner(CanEliminate
>   canElim, FSharpExpr queryProducingSequence)    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.EvalNonNestedOuter(CanEliminate
>   canElim, FSharpExpr tm)    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.clo@1737-1.Microsoft-FSharp-Linq-ForwardDeclarations-IQueryMethods-Execute[a,b](FSharpExpr`1
>   )    ...    ...    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.ArrayModule.Parallel.Map@714-3.Invoke(Int32
>   obj)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.b__c()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass11.b__10(Object
>   param0)<---

I also tried running it from C# using Parallel.For().. I am probably missing something basic. Is there an easy way to make a function thread-safe? or a query expression?

Thanks for the help!

Possible option to resolve:
When I included the call for the database context in the function in resolved the parralel exception. Such as:

```
let query_one (firstName:string) (lastName:string) =
     let db = temp_schema.GetDataContext()
     query { for a in db.Names do
             where (a.firstname = FirstName && a.secondname = LastName)
             select a } |> Seq.last
```

Comment: what line do you get that exception from?

Comment: It occurs on the first query call.. query one

Comment: The third line of query_one looks weird: `a.firstname = FirstName`, but the formal parameter is named `firstName` (lower-case `f`). Similarly `LastName`, and `List` doesn't have a member `add`.

Comment: Just to be sure: does the exception disappear if you *don't* run in parallel? E.g. if you just use `Array.map` instead of `Array.Parallel.map`?

Comment: I generalized the code so I apologize for the case-inaccuracy..

Comment: Mark, yes, if I use Array.map it works fine.. although much slower

Comment: @user1129988 Type provider uses Entity Framework under the covers, and `DbContext` is not thread-safe. So yes, creating a new context for each parallel call will alleviate the immediate problem. It would be even better would be to retrieve *all* data in one DB call, instead of trying to cover up N+1 select problem...